# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted on Production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I am getting System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted error whenever i deploy code on my production environment everything works fine on my development environment.I didn't used any thread explicitly in my code.It is web service code which takes json  from client and send it to sql stored procedure for further processing

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SaveBulkTransactionInfo(string sInputJsonString )
{
    string errorString = "";
    Services objservices = new Services();
    SaveBulkTransactionInfoRequest ObjSaveBulkTransactionInfoRequest = new SaveBulkTransactionInfoRequest();
    DateTime RequestTime, ResponseTime;
    RequestTime = DateTime.Now;
    int requestCount = 0;
    bool catchFlag = false;
    JToken json = JToken.Parse("[]");
    List<SaveBulkTransactionResponse> objResponse = new List<SaveBulkTransactionResponse>();
    int batchSize = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TransactionLimit"]);
    List<RootObject> ObjRequest1 = new List<RootObject>();
    var isBulkRequest = 0;
    Int64 id = 0;
    try
    {
        ObjRequest1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(sInputJsonString);
        requestCount = ObjRequest1.Count;
        if (requestCount > 1)
        {
            isBulkRequest = 1;
        }
        id = objservices.WriteLogToDatabase(sInputJsonString, ObjRequest1[0].Invoice[0].Username, "SaveBulkTransactionInfo", RequestTime, ObjRequest1[0].Invoice[0].POS_CODE, Convert.ToString(ObjRequest1[0].Invoice[0].CUSTOMER_ID), ObjRequest1[0].Invoice[0].DOCNO, ObjRequest1[0].Invoice[0].DOCNOPREFIX, appVersion, isBulkRequest, requestCount);
        List<List<RootObject>> objBatch = BreakIntoChunks(ObjRequest1, batchSize);
        List<RootObject> ObjRequest = objBatch[0];
        try
        {
            List<TransactionObj> lstTransactionObj = new List<TransactionObj>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ObjRequest.Count; i++)
            {

                TransactionObj objTransaction = new TransactionObj();
                Invoice objInvoice = new Invoice();
                List<Payment> lstPayment = new List<Payment>();
                List<ProductInfo> lstProductInfo = new List<ProductInfo>();
                List<NonDiscountCoupon> lstNonDiscountCoupon = new List<NonDiscountCoupon>();

                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Invoice, Invoice>();
                });

                IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                objInvoice = mapper.Map<Invoice, Invoice>(ObjRequest[i].Invoice[0]);


                /* ---------------For Payment-----------------------*/
                for (int k = 0; k < ObjRequest[i].Payment.Count; k++)
                {
                    Payment objPayment = new Payment();

                    var configPayment = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.CreateMap<Payment, Payment>();
                    });

                    IMapper mapperPayment = configPayment.CreateMapper();
                    objPayment = mapperPayment.Map<Payment, Payment>(ObjRequest[i].Payment[k]);
                    lstPayment.Add(objPayment);

                }

                /* --------------For Product----------------------------*/
                for (int j = 0; j < ObjRequest[i].Transaction[0].ProductInfo.Count; j++)
                {
                    ProductInfo objProductInfo = new ProductInfo();

                    var configProductInfo = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.CreateMap<ProductInfo, ProductInfo>();
                    });
                    IMapper mapperProductInfo = configProductInfo.CreateMapper();
                    objProductInfo = mapperProductInfo.Map<ProductInfo, ProductInfo>(ObjRequest[i].Transaction[0].ProductInfo[j]);
                    lstProductInfo.Add(objProductInfo);


                }

                /*------------------NonDiscountCoupon----------*/
                if (ObjRequest[i].NonDiscountCoupon != null)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < ObjRequest[i].NonDiscountCoupon.Count; l++)
                    {
                        NonDiscountCoupon objNonDiscountCoupon = new NonDiscountCoupon();

                        var configNonDiscountCoupon = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                        {
                            cfg.CreateMap<NonDiscountCoupon, NonDiscountCoupon>();
                        });
                        IMapper mapperNonDiscountCoupon = configNonDiscountCoupon.CreateMapper();
                        objNonDiscountCoupon = mapperNonDiscountCoupon.Map<NonDiscountCoupon, NonDiscountCoupon>(ObjRequest[i].NonDiscountCoupon[l]);
                        lstNonDiscountCoupon.Add(objNonDiscountCoupon);

                    }
                }


                objTransaction.objInvoice = objInvoice;
                objTransaction.objPayment = lstPayment;
                objTransaction.ProductInfo = lstProductInfo;
                objTransaction.NonDiscountCoupon = lstNonDiscountCoupon;
                lstTransactionObj.Add(objTransaction);

            }

            ObjSaveBulkTransactionInfoRequest.lstTransactions = lstTransactionObj;
            objResponse = objservices.SaveBulkTransaction(ObjSaveBulkTransactionInfoRequest);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorString = ex.ToString();
        }    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorString = ex.ToString();

    }
    finally
    {
        ResponseTime = DateTime.Now;
               }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JToken.Parse(strJson),Formatting.Indented);


}
```

as per my assumption from below statement

```
ObjRequest1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(sInputJsonString);
```

it directly goes to outer catch block and gives System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.I am not enable to replicate same error on my development environment.And this error comes randomly on production environment.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?